# To filter mails from inbox which are sent to another recipient?

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, office-interop

In Outlook Interop,
`using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

To filter unread emails, I'm using the following code

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace = oApp.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
Outlook.Items items = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true");
```

Likewise, Is there a way to filter the mails sent to a specific recipient other than me.

Say, filter mails sent to `abc@example.com`.
 My mail ID would also be present in those mails in To or in CC. I will be happier to find a possible way with Outlook interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a search query like the following to search for a match on the `PR_DISPLAY_TO` MAPI property (replace `0x0E04001F` with `0x0E03001F` for `PR_DISPLAY_CC`)

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001F" LIKE '%abc@example.com%'
```

Keep in mind however that `PR_DISPLAY_TO` / `PR_DISPLAY_CC` may or may not contain the email addresses; they could just contain display names.

On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), you can create a restriction on recipients (`RES_SUBRESTRICTION` / `PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS`).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) (I am its author - any language) is an option, you can use RDOFolder.[Items.Restrict](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm) - unlike Outlook Object Model, it does expand To/CC/BCC queries into recipient sub restrictions on `PR_DISPLAY_NAME` and `PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS` properties on each recipient (`RES_SUBRESTRICTION` / `PR_MESSAGE_RECIPIENTS` / `RES_OR` / `PR_DISPLAY_NAME` | `PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS`).

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Folder = Session.GetFolderFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID)
set restrItems = Folder.Items.Restrict(" TO = 'abc@example.com' ")
```

You can also specify `Recipients` property in a query - it will be matched against recipients of all types (to/cc/bcc):

```
set restrItems = Folder.Items.Restrict(" Recipients = 'abc@example.com' ")
```